# Databricks cannot access FileStore from shell command

Tags: azure-databricks

```
%sh ls /dbfs/FileStore
ls: cannot access '/dbfs/FileStore': No such file or directory
```

For some reason, I cannot access the FileStore from a notebook in my cluster. I am not sure why this is happening. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Is it Shared cluster?

Comment: It is single user.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `%fs ls`
It  shows default **DBFS** (Databricks File System).

For example I have a CSV file in DBFS

```
%fs ls dbfs:/FileStore/
```

[image]

```
%fs ls dbfs:/FileStore/tables/emp09.csv
```

[image]

If you are executing commands  `%sh`, This commands are executed on the driver node only. and will show the content on that machine.

I tried the `%sh ls /dbfs/FileStore` with out uploading a file to DBFS and tried to list the FileStore.

[image]

If you want to use the Shell command. Make sure you have the files uploaded in the DBFS and list them.

you can use the below command

```
%sh ls /dbfs/FileStore/tables/
```

[image]

**Reference:** [What is the Databricks File System (DBFS)?](https://docs.databricks.com/en/dbfs/index.html)

Comment: I have other clusters where /dbfs/FileStore is mounted and available to shell commands.

Comment: @Eric Truett updated the solution.